How to show the dragging shadow image while dragging in a react application?
I created a draggable list using react-dnd in a react application.
The name of this component is simply DraggableList. I am using DraggableList in a page of the web app and also in a FluentUi Panel in another web page.
Everything works fine except for one thing: There is a problem with the drag "shadow" image (the image that follows the cursor while you are dragging). In the main page, the shadow image is alright but in the other place where I am using DraggableList (inside the Panel), there is no shadow image. What is strange is when I remove the Panel, the shadow image appears correctly.
So I guess there is some problem rendering DraggableList inside a Panel.
I am showing you some part of the code I am using.
Thank you very much!
import React, { useEffect, FC, useRef } from 'react';
import { DragSourceMonitor, DropTargetMonitor, useDrag, useDrop } from 'react-dnd';
import styles from "./DraggableList.module.scss";
import { Icon } from '@fluentui/react';
import { DraggableListItem } from './DraggableList';
import { getEmptyImage } from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';

export interface DraggableListItemViewProps {
    item: DraggableListItem
    index: number;
    maxItemsNumber: number;
    addDraggableItem: (newDraggableListItem: DraggableListItem, hoverIndex: number) => void;
    moveDraggableItem: (dragIndex: number, hoverIndex: number) => void;
    deleteItemCallback: (deletedItem: DraggableListItem) => void;
    isDraggingOutside?: boolean | undefined;
}

interface DragItem {
    draggableItem: DraggableListItem;
    index: number;
    type: string;
}

export const DraggableListItemView: FC<DraggableListItemViewProps> = ({
    item,
    index,
    maxItemsNumber,
    moveDraggableItem,
    addDraggableItem,
    deleteItemCallback,
    isDraggingOutside
}) => {
    const refListView = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    const [{ handlerId }, dropListItem] = useDrop<DragItem, void, { handlerId: Identifier | null }>({
        accept: "draggableListItem",
        collect(monitor: DropTargetMonitor<DragItem, void>) {
            return {
                handlerId: monitor.getHandlerId(),
            }
        },
        hover(dragItem: DragItem, monitor: DropTargetMonitor<DragItem, void>) {
            if (!refListView.current) {
                return;
            }

            const dragIndex = dragItem.index;
            const hoverIndex = index;

            //Ne pas replacer l'item actuel
            if (dragIndex === hoverIndex) {
                return;
            }

            //Déterminer un rectangle sur l'écran
            const hoverBoundingRect = refListView.current?.getBoundingClientRect();

            //Obtenir le milieu vertical
            const hoverMiddleY = (hoverBoundingRect.bottom - hoverBoundingRect.top) / 2;

            //Déterminer la position de la souris
            const clientOffset = monitor.getClientOffset();

            //Obtenir le nombre de pixels par rapport au haut
            const hoverClientY = (clientOffset as XYCoord).y - hoverBoundingRect.top;

            //On effectue le déplacement seulement lorsque la souris a parcouru 
            //plus que la moitiée de la hauteur de l'item
            //Quand on drag vers le bas, déplacer seulement quand le curseur est plus bas que 50%
            //Quand on drag vers le haut, déplacer seulement quand le curseur est plus haut que 50%

            if (dragIndex === undefined) {
                //Il s'agit d'un ajout
                addDraggableItem(dragItem.draggableItem, hoverIndex);
                dragItem.index = hoverIndex;
                return;
            }

            //Drag vers le bas
            if (dragIndex < hoverIndex && hoverClientY < hoverMiddleY) {
                return;
            }

            //Drag vers le haut
            if (dragIndex > hoverIndex && hoverClientY > hoverMiddleY) {
                return;
            }

            moveDraggableItem(dragIndex, hoverIndex);
            dragItem.index = hoverIndex;
        }
    }, [maxItemsNumber, index])

    const [{ isDragging }, dragListItem, listItemDragPreview] = useDrag({
        type: "draggableListItem",
        item: () => {
            return { item, index };
        },
        collect: (monitor: DragSourceMonitor<{ id: string; index: number; }, unknown>) => ({
            isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
        })
    }, [maxItemsNumber, index])

    useEffect(() => {
        listItemDragPreview(getEmptyImage(), { captureDraggingState: false })
    }, [listItemDragPreview])

    const onKeyDownDelete = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLElement>): void => {
        if (e.key === "Enter") {
            deleteItemCallback(item)
        }
    }

    const opacity: number = (isDragging || isDraggingOutside) ? 0 : 1;

    listItemDragPreview(dragListItem(dropListItem(refListView)));

    return (
        <div
            style={{ opacity }}
            ref={refListView}
            data-handler-id={handlerId}
            className={`
                ${styles.item}
                ${styles.details}
                ${maxItemsNumber - index === 0 ? styles.firstExcluded : ""}
                ${index >= maxItemsNumber ? styles.excluded : ""}
            `}
        >
            <span>{`${index + 1}. ${item.text}`}</span>
            <div className={styles.itemIcons}>
                <Icon
                    iconName="SwitcherStartEnd"
                />
                {item.isRemovable && (
                    <Icon
                        tabIndex={0}
                        className={styles.deleteIcon}
                        iconName="Delete"
                        onClick={() => deleteItemCallback(item)}
                        onKeyDown={onKeyDownDelete}
                    />
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}



            <Panel
                headerText={"Sélection et classement des actualités"}
                isOpen={true}
                closeButtonAriaLabel="Close"
                hasCloseButton={true}
                type={PanelType.extraLarge}
                onDismiss={validate}
                layerProps={{ eventBubblingEnabled: true }}
            >
                <MessageDialog
                    message={`Vous devez sélectionner ${newsQuantity} actualité(s).`}
                    title="Actualités"
                    showMessageDialog={isValidationErrorMessageOpen}
                    closeCallback={() => hideValidationErrorMessage()}
                />

                {newsIsLoading && (
                    <Loader />
                )}

                <TooltipHost
                    content="Rechercher des sites d'actualités"
                    id="newsSitesSearchToolTip"
                >
                    <TextField
                        className={styles.searchTextBox}
                        defaultValue={""}
                        onChange={onChangeNewsSearch}
                        aria-describedby="newsSitesSearchToolTip"
                        placeholder="Rechercher dans les actualités"
                    />
                </TooltipHost>

                <div className={styles.mainDivContainer}>
                    <div className={styles.newsDisplayDiv}>
                        <div className={styles.formSectionTitle}>
                            Dernières informations de vos sources d&apos;actualités sélectionnées
                        </div>
                        <div className={styles.newsContainer}>
                            {filteredNews && filteredNews.length > 0 && (
                                filteredNews.map((n, index) =>
                                    <>
                                        <OrganizeNewsView
                                            index={index}
                                            news={n}
                                            selected={draggableListItems.some(d => d.id === n.urlPage)}
                                            onDragNewsCallback={
                                                (draggingItem: DraggableListItem | undefined) => 
                                                    setDraggingItemOutside(draggingItem)
                                            }
                                        />
                                        <Separator />
                                    </>
                                )
                            )}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={styles.draggableListDiv}>
                        <div className={styles.formSectionTitle}>
                            Ordre des actualités
                        </div>
                        <DraggableList
                            onChangeCallback={onChangeDraggableListCallback}
                            dataList={draggableListItems}
                            deleteItemConfirmMessage="Voulez-vous supprimer cette actualité?"
                            deleteItemConfirmTitle="Suppression de l'actualité"
                            maxItemsNumber={newsQuantity}
                            draggingItemOutside={draggingItemOutside}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className={styles.footer}>
                    <Stack horizontal disableShrink>
                        <CommonButton
                            buttonId="btnValider"
                            buttonText="Valider"
                            iconName="Save"
                            clickCallback={validate}
                        />
                        <CommonButton
                            buttonId="btnAnnuler"
                            buttonText="Annuler"
                            iconName="Cancel"
                            clickCallback={cancel}
                        />
                    </Stack>
                </div>
            </Panel>```

